# Why GCM is not coming on some phones?

Tags: android, google-maps, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-manifest

I am facing some issues on not receiving notifications on some phones. I am not receiving GCM intent also. Here are the logs when I am calling GCM registration. On phone like Nexus, Moto it is running perfectly fine. But on lower end phones like Lava and Karbonn, I am facing this problem.

D/GCM     (  950): GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService (has extras) } com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER

V/ActivityManager(  649): Broadcast: Intent { act=com.google.android.intent.action.GCM_RECONNECT flg=0x14 (has extras) } ordered=true userid=0 callerApp=null

D/ActivityThread(  950): BDC-Calling onReceive: intent=Intent { act=com.google.android.intent.action.GCM_RECONNECT flg=0x14 (has extras) }, ordered=true, receiver=com.google.android.gms.gcm.bf@41f4f2e0, IIntentReceiver=41efeef8

D/PowerManagerService(  649): acquireWakeLockInternal: lock=1114432392, flags=0x1, tag="GCM_CONN_ALARM", ws=WorkSource{10009 com.google.android.gms}, uid=10009, pid=950

D/PowerManagerNotifier(  649): onWakeLockAcquired: flags=1, tag="GCM_CONN_ALARM", packageName=com.google.android.gms, ownerUid=10009, ownerPid=950, workSource=WorkSource{10009 com.google.android.gms}

D/dalvikvm(  950): threadid=22 (GCMWriter): calling run()

D/PowerManagerService(  649): acquireWakeLockInternal: lock=1114432392, flags=0x1, tag="GCM_CONN_ALARM", ws=WorkSource{10009 com.google.android.gms}, uid=10009, pid=950

D/dalvikvm(  950): threadid=26 (GCMWriter): calling run()

D/PowerManagerService(  649): releaseWakeLockInternal: lock=1114432392 [GCM_CONN_ALARM], flags=0x0, total_time=150ms

D/PowerManagerNotifier(  649): onWakeLockReleased: flags=1, tag="GCM_CONN_ALARM", packageName=com.google.android.gms, ownerUid=10009, ownerPid=950, workSource=WorkSource{10009 com.google.android.gms}

Here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="<PACKAGE>"><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />


<permission android:name="<PACKAGE>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="<PACKAGE>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />


<application
    android:name="<PACKAGE>.ApplicationSingleton"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name="<PACKAGE>.ui.activity.WalkThroughActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>


    </activity>


    <receiver
        android:name="<PACKAGE>.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="<PACKAGE>" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

    <service android:name="<PACKAGE>.gcm.GcmIntentService" />

    <activity
        android:name="<PACKAGE>.ui.activity.VendorDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/NoTitleDialog"/>

    <activity
        android:name="<PACKAGE>.ui.activity.HomeActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"/>

    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

GCM should work as long as the device is on at least Android version 2.2, has the Play Store app installed and a logged in Google Account.

Make sure that account sync is switched to ON as well.

Comment: The notification was coming on the same phone a day ago and now it is giving this error. I edited my logs. Do I have to change something in my manifest file for making it work on low end phones?